# Import with replacement in Python

Tags: python, import, module

When I do `import module` (or more complex versions of it), it imports `module` once.

If I change the code in the module, `import module` does nothing: all functions are the same. Only re-running the source itself helps.

Is there a way to `import` with replacing existing definitions in Python?

Comment: Is [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Robinson mentioned, [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) should do what you want.

Better yet, if you use IPython, you can set it up so that it automatically re-imports all of your libraries before executing any of your code. If you're not using IPython but you're working with a Python shell, you should consider switching -- it's tremendously useful. [You can read more about it here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this: `from module.submodule import *` and `imp.reload(module.submodule)` (Py 3 version of `reload()`, which ends with `NameError`.

Comment: I don't think that `from module.submodule import *` is compatible with `imp.reload`. You will need to `from module import submodule` then `imp.reload(submodule)`.

Comment: AFAIK, `from module import submodule` isn't a full equivalent to `from module.submodule import *`. E.g., I access class as `submodule.Class()` or `Class()` in these respective cases.

Comment: @Anton `from module.submodule import *` is bad form, you shouldn't be doing it. But if that's what you need, I believe you need to go with IPython's `autoreload`.